# How to pass an array of setting values across multiple classes, efficiently

Tags: php, class, oop, dependency-injection, singleton

I have a settings array of config values that don't change and need to use these values in various classes.

```
$settings = ['foo' => 'bar', 'license_id' => '12345'];
```

Currently, I am using a static class and anytime I need a config value inside a class I do this:

```
$this->global_config = MyClass::get_global_config_array();
if ( $this->global_config['license_id'] ) do this . . .
```

Is there another way than using a global, dependency injection, or a singleton class? I make a lot of calls to MyClass::get_global_config_array() and was looking for a way to be more efficient.

FYI: I am new to OOP, but not procedural.

```
class Settings() {
  public static function global_config_array() {
    $settings = ['foo' => 'bar', 'license_id' => '12345'];
    return $settings;
  }  
}

class Render_Setup_Page() {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->global_settings = Settings::global_config_array();
  }
  public function check_license() {
    if ( $this->global_settings['license_id'] ) do this . . .
  }
}

class Render_Profile_page() {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->global_settings = Settings::global_config_array();
  }
  public function user_info() {
    ret 'first name: ' . $this->global_settings['foo'] );
  }
}
```

UPDATE:

To add more content to this request. I am building a WordPress plugin that has plugin settings that are divided into three types: static, dynamic, and the theme customizer.

I merge the three into a global settings array and pass the array around to several functions. Having them in a single array it eliminates a lot of calls for data. Especially in a theme template.

Based on the suggestion from @miken32 to use trait, I have come up with the following example:

```
trait Global_Settings { 
    private array $static = [
        "foo"               => "bar", 
        "license_id"        => "12345"
    ];
    
    private array $dynamic = [
        'plugin_build'      => '73686572726965206',
        'plugin_version'    => '1.0.0',
        'plugin_prefix'     => 'xyx',
    ];
    
    private array $customizer = [
        'plugin_123'        => 'hello',
        'plugin_456'        => 'there',
    ];
    
    private function get_static_settings() {        
        return $this->static;
    }

    private function get_dynamic_settings() {
        return $this->dynamic;
    }

    private function get_customizer_settings() {
        return $this->customizer;
    }
    
    private function global_settings() {
        return array_merge(￼
            $this->static,
            $this->dynamic,
            $this->customizer,
        );
    }
}

class Do_Something {    
    use Global_Settings;

    public function render_something() {        
        error_log( print_r($this->get_dynamic_settings(), TRUE) );
        error_log( print_r($this->get_static_settings(), TRUE) );
        error_log( print_r($this->get_customizer_settings(), TRUE) );
        error_log( print_r($this->global_settings(), TRUE) );
             
        // Get a specific settings array.
        $output = 'Your' . $this->get_dynamic_settings['foo'] . ' license is: ' . $this->get_dynamic_settings['license_id'];

        // Or get all of them at once.
        extract( $this->global_settings );
        $output = $plugin_123 . ' your' . $foo . ' license is: ' . $license_id . ' for version ' . $plugin_version;

        return $output; 
    }    
}

$obj = new Do_Something();
$obj->render_something();
```

My follow up question is how to assign the results from another class that has a settings array to the $static property in the trait Global_Settings?

```
class Static_Array {
  public array() {
    return [
        "foo"               => "bar", 
        "license_id"        => "12345"
    ];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these values really are fixed, you could have the classes import a [trait](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) that holds the settings and also incorporates any common functionality you need.

```php
trait HasSettings
{
    private array $settings = ["foo" => "bar", "license_id" => "12345"];

    private function hasLicense(): bool
    {
        return !empty($this->settings["license_id"]);
    }

    private function getFoo(): string
    {
        return $this->settings["foo"] ?? "";
    }
}

class Render_Setup_Page
{
    use HasSettings;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    public function check_license()
    {
        if ( $this->hasLicense()) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}

class Render_Profile_page
{
    use HasSettings;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    public function user_info()
    {
        // don't ever echo from a class method
        return 'first name: ' . $this->getFoo();
    }
}
```

Providing methods to access these values is a good idea, but you also have access to the [private](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) array via `$this->settings`.

Comment: Yes the values are fixed. I was not aware of trait. It seems to be what I am after and a better option over global and a singleton class. Am I correct, by using import HasSettings it's not running HasSettings again, like in the case of a singleton and just passing the results of HasSettings to another class?

Comment: I tried to find import in the php docs. I am wondering why import over use HasSettings?

Comment: Sorry, should have been "use". Fixed now! And yes, a trait is basically just a way to copy/paste code into your classes so nothing is being executed when you import the trait.

Comment: First trait was a great new thing to learn, thanks. It has opened up a lot of thinking. I almost have this working except, I am struggling with one beginner task. The array in the $settings property, I want to pass the array to $settings from another class. The passed array is long and I want to keep HasSetting clean and short, and the getFoo() method is a dynamic array. How do I pass the results from another class to private array $settings = outside class? I have tried using a static class private array $settings = Test::BigArry() and using an object.

Comment: I would create a public method to set the contents of $settings. You should also look into the __call() method, which would let you call methods like getFoo() dynamically.

Comment: I updated the question with a working example based on your code. I have added a public method in a new class, but I am lost as how to assign the results to the property $static in the trait Global_Settings. You can reference my example code in the updated question. __call() seems interesting. I have not wrapped my head around where I would use it just yet, but I will keep in mind.